# In Specflow can I perform setup once then run a bunch of independent verifications as separate tests?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, specflow

I'm writing automated tests for a set of APIs. I have 1 API to run a search and another to get the results. I want to run the search once then have several tests Get the results and run verifications.

```
RunOnce: 
    Given I have access to the User 'testUser'
    When I call POST /api/Search with
    """
    {
        "query": "legal",
        "snippetLength": 15,
        "resultSize": 4,
    ...
    }
    """

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify Result Size
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The result size is X

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify Filters
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The filters are X

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify Sorting
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The sorting is X

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify snippet
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The snippet length is X
```

Is this a really bad pattern? I don't want to have to run the search for each Scenario due to timing. But at the same time I want the tests separate so I don't have all the Assertions in a single scenario for efficient result analysis.

I think the only way to do this would be adding a tag to the Feature and implementing this in the TestHooks file. But then I lose a lot of the visibility if there are failures in the POST call.

Comment: Is running the search taking a long time? And what is your definition of "long"? I frequently see these kinds of questions, and it leads me to believe that Gherkin is the wrong tool for this kind of test, or this could be premature optimization.

Comment: Are you running your tests in parallel?

Comment: I'm also confused by the difference in behavior between POST and GET `/api/Search`. For a REST service it doesn't make sense. It makes sense for a regular web page. The POST is submitting the form. The GET is for displaying the form with the typical workflow being a) GET; b) POST. Subsequent GETs would be seen as viewing the search form without submitting it, unless the web page remembers your last search.

Comment: Thanks Greg, our workflow is actually to send the POST call to submit the search (this will then make several calls to different search connectors). Then we have another API GET /api/SearchStatus/:searchId that i didn't originally mention for simplicity that will just return Complete, in_progress, error. Then we can call GET /api/Search/:searchId to view the results.

Comment: Ok, so the POST returns a search Id that you can GET later?

Comment: Yes exactly. So i can call the GET and pass in the same searchId several times and get the same results

Comment: I'll update my answer tomorrow, but the change is not very big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Gherkin language feature that allows you to do this. Instead, consider using the [FeatureContext](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/FeatureContext.html) to store the search results, since the FeatureContext object is shared by all scenarios in a feature. You would still use a scenario background for your Given step that submits the search. The step definition would check to see if the feature context already has the search results, and if so, the Given step would simply do nothing. If the search results do not exist in the feature context, then execute the code to POST the search.

Any When or Then steps operating on the search results should pull the results from the feature context.

Feature file:

```
Background: 
    Given I have access to the User 'testUser'
    When I call POST /api/Search with
    """
    {
        "query": "legal",
        "snippetLength": 15,
        "resultSize": 4,
    ...
    }
    """

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify Result Size
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The result size is X

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify Filters
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The filters are X

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify Sorting
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The sorting is X

Scenario: SearchAPI - Verify snippet
    When I call GET /api/Search
    Then The snippet length is X
```

Next, use the `FeatureContext` to store and retrieve the searchId, and results:

```cs
[Binding]
public class SearchSteps
{
    private readonly FeatureContext feature;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the API search Id
    /// </summary>
    private string SearchId
    {
        get => (string)feature["foo"];
        set => feature["foo"] = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the API search results
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<X> Results
    {
        get => (IEnumerable<X>)feature["searchResults"];
        set => feature["searchResults"] = value;
    }

    public SearchSteps(FeatureContext feature)
    {
        this.feature = feature;
    }

    [When(@"I call POST /api/Search with")]
    public void WhenICallPOST_api_searchWith(string json)
    {
        if (SearchId != null)
            return;

        var request = // parse json variable into object
        SearchId = api.PostSearch(request);
    }

    [When(@"I call GET /api/Search")]
    public void WhenICallGET_api_Search()
    {
        Results = api.GetSearch(SearchId);
    }

    [Then(@"The result size is (\d+)")]
    public void ThenResultSizeIs(int expectedResultSize)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(Results.Count(), expectedResultSize);
    }

    // Other 'Then' steps make assertions on Results property
}
```

You can magically get access to the FeatureContext, because SpecFlow already registers that object with the dependency injection framework. Simply add a FeatureContext parameter to the constructor for your step definition to get access to this object.

I find it nice to create private properties that get/set values on the `FeatureContext` object, so you only cast objects in one spot. Plus it gives things a meaningful name, and makes dealing with the FeatureContext easier in your step definitions.

You would replace `IEnumerable<X> Results` with the name of the type for the response to `GET /api/Search/:searchId`.

Comment: So basically run the steps in the background step (which gets executed before each scenario) but add a flag to the feature context that says, "if this was already run, skip it?"

Comment: @RyanDorendorf: I updated my answer with some of the info you provided in the comments.